# This jQuery seems like it should work

Tags: jquery, toggle, fadein, fadeout

I've trawled for hours over this piece of jQuery and I still can't get it to work.

When I click one toggle, the rest open.

I really need some help on this as it's for an important project.

I'm not too good with jQuery and I've neatened it up as much as I can, but I'm really stuck.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(function( $ )
{
    var about = $( "#about" ),
        contact = $( "#contact" ),
        download = $( "#download" ),
        abouttoggle = $( "#abouttoggle"),
        contacttoggle = $( "#contacttoggle"),
        downloadtoggle = $( "#downloadtoggle"); 

    abouttoggle.click(
        function( event )
        { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            if ( about.is( ":visible" ) )
            { 
                about.fadeOut( 500 ); 
                abouttoggle.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            }
            else
            {
                about.fadeIn( 500 ); 
                abouttoggle.css("background-color","#E0E0E0").fadeIn( 500 );
            }

            contact.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            contact.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            download.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            download.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
        }
    );   

    contacttoggle.click(
        function( event )
        { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            if ( contact.is( ":visible" ) )
            { 
                contact.fadeOut( 500 ); 
                contacttoggle.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            }
            else
            {
                contact.fadeIn( 500 ); 
                contacttoggle.css("background-color","#E0E0E0").fadeIn( 500 );
            }

            about.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            abouttoggle.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            download.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            download.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
        }
    );   

    downloadtoggle.click(
        function( event )
        { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            if ( download.is( ":visible" ) )
            { 
                download.fadeOut( 500 ); 
                downloadtoggle.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            }
            else
            {
                download.fadeIn( 500 ); 
                downloadtoggle.css("background-color","#E0E0E0").fadeIn( 500 );
            }

            contact.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            contact.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
            about.fadeOut( 500 ); 
            about.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
        }
    );   

});
```

and the (relevant) html:

```
<div align="center" class="info">
    <a id="abouttoggle" href="#" class="aboutbutton">about</a> | <a id="contacttoggle" href="#" class="contactbutton">contact</a> | <a id="downloadtoggle" href="#" class="downloadbutton">downloads</a>
    </div>

    <div align="center" class="about" id="about">
    about stuff
    </div>

    <div align="center" class="contact" id="contact">
    contact stuff
    </div>

    <div align="center" class="download" id="download">
    download stuff
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you indent the code?

Comment: That's still not properly indented.  And where is the HTML that goes with this?

Comment: Besides adding whitespace, I replaced multiple 'var [name]' expressions with a comma separated list.  Shouldn't change operation, but anyone reviewing the code should be aware of the code change.  @Stanley Hutcheon, you should use the comma separated list when initializing variables.

Comment: It totally matters.  When it's properly indented, it's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks, as I said, i'm new to jQuery. I had no idea you could do that :P

Comment: Be thankful that rockerest was kind enough to properly indent all the code in your question.  That really helps everyone.  Now if you could add the relevant portions of HTML, it would be great.

Comment: Just an FYI, the `align` attribute has been deprecated.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want this code to do.  Example... you `fadeOut()` an element, then tell the same element to `fadeIn()` on the very next line.  Why?  Since jQuery animations are asynchronous, these two animations happen simultaneously. But since they're doing opposing animations on a single element simultaneously, I'm not sure what's supposed to happen.

Comment: thanks everyone, I fixed it. It was basically what @Sparky672 just said. (If you fadeIn an element that has already faded in, it will face out and vice versa)

Comment: @StanleyHutcheon That's not correct.  Not only is that not how jQuery works, but that's also not what you're doing.  You're fading the element OUT and THEN fading it in.

Comment: Stanley, please post your solution as an answer below and then "accept" your own answer.  It's the proper way to use this site when you answer your own questions.  Thank-you.

Comment: **Quote:**  _"(If you fadeIn an element that has already faded in, it will face out and vice versa)"_  Stanley, please read my comment again... because that's **not** what I said.  **It's your code, not jQuery,** that's telling it to fade OUT and then immediately fade back IN.

Comment: sorry, I'm extremely tired. You were right @Sparky672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `fadeIn` on the menu elements right after you fade them out.

Make all of these lines:

```
contact.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
```

look like this:

```
contacttoggle.css("background-color","transparent").fadeIn( 500 );
```

You're doing it correctly in the `contacttoggle.click` function.

You could also be using `$(this)` instead of pre-defining variables.  `$(this)` references the jQuery object that the function is acting on.